# Help to the way to write a query for the requirement

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I need to write a SQL-Server query but I don't know how to solve. I have a table RealtimeData with data:

```
 Time                   |    Value
4/29/2009 12:00:00 AM   |   3672.0000
4/29/2009 12:01:00 AM   |   3645.0000
4/29/2009 12:02:00 AM   |   3677.0000
4/29/2009 12:03:00 AM   |   3634.0000
4/29/2009 12:04:00 AM   |   3676.0000      // is EOD of day "4/29/2009"
4/30/2009 12:00:00 AM   |   3671.0000
4/30/2009 12:01:00 AM   |   3643.0000
4/30/2009 12:02:00 AM   |   3672.0000
4/30/2009 12:03:00 AM   |   3634.0000
4/30/2009 12:04:00 AM   |   3632.0000
4/30/2009 12:05:00 AM   |   3672.0000      // is EOD of day "4/30/2009"
5/1/2009 12:00:00 AM    |   3673.0000
5/1/2009 12:01:00 AM    |   3642.0000
5/1/2009 12:02:00 AM    |   3672.0000
5/1/2009 12:03:00 AM    |   3634.0000
5/1/2009 12:04:00 AM    |   3635.0000      // is EOD of day "5/1/2009"
```

I want to get the EOD's data of days which exist in table. (EOD = end of day). With the my sample's data, I will need to reture a table like following:

```
   Time      |    Value
4/29/2009    |  3676.0000
4/30/2009    |  3672.0000
5/1/2009     |  3635.0000
```

Note: I write the comment so that you can know where is EOD. And SQL Server is version 2005.

Note: the data in RealtimeData table is very large with more than 400.000 rows. Please help me to write in optimization.

Please help me to solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?!?

Comment: Performance will be an issue if this table collects tons of data (like a row every second for months or years). `DateTime` make for poor keys and indicies. Can you denormalize the date into indexable parts or maybe extract the eod data into a separate summary table with a daily job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH RankedRealTimeData AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [TIME], 121) 
      ORDER BY Time DESC) AS RN
  FROM RealTimeData
)
SELECT * FROM RankedRealTimeData WHERE RN=1;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, Time)`?

Comment: Don't you need another argument for the DATEPART function?

Comment: The query returns the correct result if you make the change to the `DATEPART` function as indicated above.

Comment: This will not differentiate between records from different years. You could partition by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [TIME], 121) instead of DATEPART

Comment: @Chris good point. I wonder what gives better performance, casting it as a `VARCHAR` or having multiple `PARTITION BY` criteria (`DATEPART` year, `DATEPART` dayofyear)

Comment: @ongle: Both methods defeat the possibility of using an index, which I would guess (without having measured, admittedly) is a much greater performance penalty than the difference between two ways of extracting the components of the date.  So if performance is a priority, I would do as you suggest in your comment to the OP question above, store components of the date separately, and index them.

Comment: @Bill Karwin, rather than splitting up the real date/time field into two fields which would change how the rest of the application interacts with this table the OP can create a persisted calculated field on the table which is just the date portion and then he can create an index on that persisted calculated field.

Comment: @Sam: Good point, I overlook the feature of calculated fields (and expression indexes) since I most often use MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    CAST(Time as DATE) EodDate, 
    (
        SELECT  TOP 1
                Value
        FROM    RealtimeData I
        WHERE   CAST(I.Time AS Date) = CAST(O.Time AS Date)
        ORDER BY    Time DESC
    ) EodValue
FROM 
    RealtimeData O
GROUP BY CAST(Time as DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(Time as DATE)
```

Comment: The `DATE` datatype is new with SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @ongle, thanks for pointing that out.  I didn't realize.  Anyways, there are other simple ways to get the date component if you need something that's not sql2008 specific.

Answer (score 0):

;With wcte as (
Select  vTime,vValue,Row_Number() over (partition by Convert(DateTime,Convert(varchar(10),vTime,110)) order by vTime Desc) rno
from @vTable 
)Select vTime,vValue from wcte where rno = 1

Answer (score -1):

Using Sql 92 is the best solution for anyone who dont want to use specified DB system.

Like this:

```
Select A.*
From RealtimeData A
Where A.RTime >= (
    select Max(B.RTime)
    From RealtimeData B
    Where Cast((B.RTime - A.RTime) as int) <= 0
)
```

Comment: Very banana. No optimization.