# SQL query to find the highest paid salary for each lanauges

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

As I am not expert in writing the SQL queries so want for help.
I have a table called programmer whose structure & data look like:

```
PNAME,PROF1,PROF2,SALARY
```

In prof1 data are:

> PASCAL,CLIPPER,COBOL,CPP,COBOL,PASCAL,ASSEMBLY,PASCAL,BASIC,C,PASCAL,FOXPRO.

In prof2 data are:

> BASIC,COBOL,DBASE,DBASE,ORACLE,DBASE,CLIPPER,C,DBASE,COBOL,ASSEMBLY,BASIC,C.

In salary data are:

> 3200,2800,3000,2900,4500,2500,2800,3000,3200,2500,3600,3700,3500.

I need a query to display the names of highest paid programmer for each language, which means I need to display the maximum salary & person name for each language.
I tried my best to get the result but didn't get the answer.
Can you help me?

Comment: Can you at least show what you've tried? Even if it's not working, that way we will be a little more excited to help you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help to the way to write a query for the requirement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726369/help-to-the-way-to-write-a-query-for-the-requirement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I like Gordon's answer, you can do it with a common table expression and a simple left join;

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT PNAME, SALARY, PROF1 PROF FROM programmer
  UNION 
  SELECT PNAME, SALARY, PROF2      FROM programmer
)
SELECT p1.PNAME, p1.PROF, p1.SALARY
FROM cte p1
LEFT JOIN cte p2
  ON p1.PROF = p2.PROF AND p1.SALARY < p2.SALARY
WHERE p2.PNAME IS NULL;
```

[EDIT: An SQLfiddle for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a09d/1).

The union flattens PROF1 and PROF2 to separate rows, and the left join basically finds programmers where there exists no better paid programmer with the same proficiency.

Comment: thanks joachim for your reply.....this is the query which i am looking for....it give me the desired output....thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function `row_number()` is the best approach for this.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by language order by salary desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If there are multiple programmers with the same salary, this returns one of them.  If you want all of them, use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

On re-reading the query, I think the "language" could be in either `prof1` or `prof2`.  This complicates the query.  Probably the simplest way is to use a window function to get the max for each and then compare the salaries:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(salary) over (partition by prof1) as max1,
             max(salary) over (partition by prof2) as max2
      from t
     ) t
where (salary = max1 and max1 >= max2) or
      (salary = max2 and max2 >= max1)
```

Comment: Can you point to documentation for row_number? I've never heard of it, and I'm curious to know how it works

Comment: i use this query:-select * from row_number(partition by prof1) as sal from programmer......but not able to compare the prof1 and prof2.....your query seems good i will test it & let you know about the result....thanks for your help....

Comment: `row_number()` is inappropriate here, unless he wants to run multiple queries for each language.  Most SQL implementations include a simpler `SELECT TOP 1` or `SELECT ... LIMIT 1` syntax.

Comment: @DougM . . . Those don't work so well when you are trying to get the top value from each *group*.

Comment: You're doing a subquery anyway, Gordon.  The best answer is probably to just grab the MAX(salary) and filter by that.

Comment: @DougM . . . I very much disagree in the one-column case.  On databases that support them, window functions are generally faster than aggregation/join methods.  In addition, they give you the option of choosing one "best" match or "all best" matches within a group (`row_number()` versus `rank()`/`dense_rank()`).

Comment: *shrug*.  With as ugly a data-set as presented here, speed is less important than clarity.  If he were fine-tuning a known good query to run faster, I wouldn't argue the point.  But until he has a working result set, picking a "generally faster" method over a slower but clearer method is premature optimization.

Comment: @DougM *"..speed is less important than clarity."* -- what kind of sql developer are you? You should **always** think speed over clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You have a poorly normalized data-set, which happens sometimes but is worth revising for performance reasons.

To get the query you're looking for, you need to derive a set of all distinct languages, pull out an identifier for the maximum salary, and then reference the programmer with that salary.  There are a variety of ways of achieve this, the simpliest way may be with a trio of subqueries.

```
SELECT 
  lang.prof,
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 pname
    FROM programmer
    WHERE prof1 = lang.prof OR prof2 = lang.prof
    ORDER BY salary DESC
  ) as Name,
  (
    SELECT MAX(Salary)
    FROM programmer
    WHERE prof1 = lang.prof OR prof2 = lang.prof
  ) as MaxSalary
FROM (
  SELECT prof1 as prof FROM programmer 
  UNION
  SELECT prof2 as prof FROM programmer 
) AS lang
```

Note that this query is **NOT** optimized, and is far from the most efficient way to query your table.  If possible, re-structure your data to have programmers, languages, and their proficiencies on separate tables.

A cleaner implementation, with a nested subquery.  More queries, but you're querying `Programmer` by a direct reference and can add any arbitrary rows.

```
SELECT 
  Lang.prof,
  P.PName,
  P.Salary
FROM 
(
    SELECT LL.prof, MAX(sP.salary) as MaxSalary
    (
      SELECT prof1 as prof FROM programmer 
      UNION
      SELECT prof2 as prof FROM programmer 
    ) as LL
    INNER JOIN programer sP
        ON LL.prof = sP.prof1 OR LL.prof = sP.prof2
    GROUP BY LL.prof
) as Lang
INNER JOIN programmer P
  ON (Lang.prof = P.prof1 OR P.prof2)
  AND lang.MaxSalary = P.salary
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select lang.prof1, max(lang.Max_Sal) from (
select prof1, max(salary) as Max_Sal from programmer group by PROF1
union
select prof2, max(salary) as Max_Sal from programmer group by PROF2) as lang group by lang.PROF1
```

Comment: Please be mindful of your formatting. Code should be formatted as code for readability.